That was a weird thing for her to say. VS It was weird for her to say such a thing
Someone is telling about how it is easy to mishear a speaker of another language. In one case she hears a word which doesn't make sense in that situation, because she is sure what she heard was right. Then she finds out that what she had heard was actually another word which sounds almost the same as what she believed she had heard. She tells about it now (the mishearing, the words, how it happened, how she felt when she heard it, etc). At one point, she said:
That was a weird thing for her to say.
I couldn't have made up that beautiful sentence myself. As a non-native speaker, I would have said:
It was weird for her to say such a thing.
Would my sentence have meant the same or would it somehow have sounded unidiomatic?

The noun phrase can be complemented by an infinitive clause: Stones may seem like a weird thing to eat but they help birds digest their food.

The adjective alone can be so complemented: Stones are weird to eat but they help birds digest.

Effectively, it would have meant the same.
That was a weird thing for her to say means that the word itself was strange.
It was weird for her to say such a thing means that the circumstance of her saying it was strange.
(Note: The original meaning of weird was 'strange in a frightening way, like something supernatural', but in recent years it has become fashionable to use it for anything the speaker finds odd.)
